# Redirect to the same page after removing record from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

How to redirect to the same view (handlebar) after performing remove data operation in mongodb? I'm trying to perform `res.render` but it says that web site cannot be reached. Thank you for your help.

**Controller**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Departments = require('../models/department');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/add_department', userAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
 Departments.find(function(err, departments) {
  if (err) {
   throw err;
  }
  res.render('add_department', {title:'Add New Department', departments: departments, name: departments.name, id: departments._id})
 })
})
router.delete('/remove_department/:id', function(req, res) {
 Departments.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
   res.statusCode = 404;
   throw err;
  } else {
   doc.remove(function(err) {
    if (err) {
     res.statusCode = 404;
     throw err;
    } else {
     res.render('add_department', {title:'Add New Department', departments: departments, name: departments.name, id: departments._id})
    }
   })
  }
 })
 
})
```

**Handlebar**

```html
<div class="container">
<h2>Departments List</h2>
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <form method="POST" action="/departments/create_department">
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Department Name" name="departmentName"></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="sumit">Add Department</button></td>
   </form>
   <td><button class="btn btn-info">Update</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-info">Clear</button></td>
  </tr>
  {{#each departments}}
  <tr>
   <form method="POST" action="/departments/remove_department/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE">
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Remove</button></td>
   </form>
   <form method="POST" action="/departments/edit_department">
    <td><button class="btn btn-warning" value={{id}} type="submit">Edit</button></td>
   </form>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
 </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this would be handled by issuing an actual redirect, rather than just rendering the page in question:

`res.redirect('/add_department');`

Possibly with some additional meta indicating that the deletion was successful.

That said, there's no specific reason why you *can't* render inside a delete handler, so I would recommend using a debugger and stepping through the code in the handler to figure out why it's erroring.